# Factory Pattern with Static Factory method or Constructor

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor, factory

I have a hierarchy of classes `RequestParams` , all can be created with `ExtArgs`.

```
public interface RequestParams {
}
```

I also created a Factory `RequestsFactory` looking like this:

```
public class RequestFactory<P extends RequestParams> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestFactory.class);
    final Class<P> paramsClass;

    public RequestFactory(Class<P> paramsClass) {
        this.paramsClass = paramsClass;
    }

    public Request<P> create(ExternalArgs args)  {
        P params = null;
        try {
            params = paramsClass.getDeclaredConstructor(ExternalArgs.getClass()).newInstance(args);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to generate request", e);
        }
        return new Request<>("get", Collections.singletonList(params));
    }

    static <P extends RequestParams> RequestFactory<P> createFactory(
            final Class<P> paramsClass) {
        return new RequestFactory<P>(paramsClass);
    }

}
```

where my client code is s follows:

```
Request devInfoRequest = RequestFactory.createFactory(RequestType.SYSTEM_INFO.getRequestClass()).create(externalArgs);
```

I use this ENUM in order map request types:

```
public enum RequestType {
    SYSTEM_INFO(DeviceInfoParams.class),
    INTERFACES(InterfacesParams.class)
}
```

My question is - How can use this, since I can't add neither constructor nor static builder to the RequestParams interface (or abstract class) ?

**EDIT:** (After [AdamSkywalker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35896072?noredirect=1)):
I want my client code to be:

```
Request<InterfacesParams> interfacesRequest =
                RequestFactory.<InterfacesParams>createFactory(RequestType.INTERFACES.create(externalArgs)).create("get");
```

But it requires the enum return function to match the generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've observed, the problem with the built-in `enum` feature is that every enum-value has to have the same type; they can't have different type arguments (in fact, the enum-class won't even accept a type parameter).

One option is to roll your own enumeration — just write a `class RequestType<P extends RequestParam>` with a private constructor and a normal static field for each instance.

But if the `RequestType` and `RequestFactory<...>` types really only have what you've shown here, then it probably makes more sense to just merge them, by writing:

```
public final class RequestFactory<P extends RequestParams> {
    public static final RequestFactory<DeviceInfoParams> SYSTEM_INFO =
        new RequestFactory<>(DeviceInfoParams::new);
    public static final RequestFactory<InterfacesParams> INTERFACES =
        new RequestFactory<>(InterfacesParams::new);

    private final Function<ExternalArgs, P> mRequestParamsCreator;

    private RequestFactory(final Function<ExternalArgs, P> requestParamsCreator) {
        mRequestParamsCreator = requestParamsCreator;
    }

    public Request<P> create(final ExternalArgs externalArgs) {
        final P requestParams = mRequestParamsCreator.apply(externalArgs);
        return new Request<P>("get", Collections.singletonList(requestParams));
    }
}
```

(Note: the above uses some Java 8 / JDK 1.8 features for conciseness. If you're still using an older version of Java, the above approach will still work, but you'll have to write a bit of boilerplate to fill in the gaps. Likewise if the relevant constructors of `DeviceInfoParams` and `InterfacesParams` declare any checked exceptions, since in that case they can't be implicitly converted to `java.util.function.Function`s.)

You can then create requests by writing (for example):

```
final Request<DeviceInfoParams> systemInfoRequest =
    RequestFactory.SYSTEM_INFO.create(externalArgs);
final Request<InterfacesParams> interfacesRequest =
    RequestFactory.INTERFACES.create(externalArgs);
```

As with AdamSkywalker's approach, this avoids reflection completely.

Comment: This is beautiful, pretty much what I was looking for. Will test first thing Monday morning.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not exactly what you're looking for, but your code is so over engineered. Why not:

```
public enum RequestType {
    SYSTEM_INFO {
        public RequestParams create(ExternalArgs args) { return new DeviceInfoParams(args); }
    },
    INTERFACES {
        public RequestParams create(ExternalArgs args) { return new InterfacesParams(args); }
    };

    abstract RequestParams create(ExternalArgs args);
}
```

And then call it without reflection tricks:

```
Request req = new Request("get", singletonList(SYSTEM_INFO.create(args)));
```

You may still use your factory, but the point is to remove the reflection complexity.

Comment: I really liked the idea of getting rid of reflection.